# Ajax request using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have to make ajax request for mobile web app, I used the following code

```
$.ajax({
        type: type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: requestURL, // Location of the service        
        //  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // content type sent to server

        dataType: "xml", //Expected data format from server
        processData: false, //True or False
        success: successCallback, //On Successfull service call
        error: serviceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
```

But it failed with error "Error: Access is denied. I am calling .aspx service from javascript

Comment: are you doing a cross-origin ajax call?

Comment: You need to be more specific, what is your requesturl and what is your backend-script?

Comment: you can't do cross domain request. i think you need to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: That is not a very helpful code segment.  That is just "How to use AJAX with jQuery."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit AJAX requests to domains other than the one serving the web page. If it is a sub domain causing the problems, you can use this code to resolve it.

```
document.domain = location.host.replace(/^.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/g,'$1');
```

Comment: or if its an external service that supports JSONP, then JSONP could be used.

Comment: the responce of api is xml, how should i used JSONP